# How to remove form when Mat-stepper index changes

Tags: html, angular, typescript, material-ui

I am using this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-component-1a7mh5?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) example to dynamically create forms in mat-stepper.
I have 3 steppers Personal Details, Address and Contact.
However, when I open the Address form and then switch to contact I want the address form to disappear. 
Below is my code. Can someone help me to point out my mistake?

Code for Mat-stepper in HTML

```
  <mat-step label="Personal Details" state="chat">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-10">
          <button mat-icon-button color="primary" matTooltip="Create New Form" (click)="addPersonalDetails()">
            <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
    <div>
      <hr />
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
<mat-step label="Address" state="chat">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-10">
          <button mat-icon-button color="primary" matTooltip="Create New AddressForm" (click)="addAddress()">
            <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
    <div>
      <hr />
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
<mat-step label="Contact" state="chat">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-10">
          <button mat-icon-button color="primary" matTooltip="Create New Contact Form" (click)="addContact()">
            <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
    <div>
      <hr />
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
```

Typescript Code

```
  addPersonalDetails() {
  this.service.setRootViewContainerRef(this.viewContainerRef);
 this.service.addDynamicPersonalComponent();
  }
  addAddress() {
this.service.setRootViewContainerRef(this.viewContainerRef);
this.service.addDynamicAddressComponent();
}
addContact() {
this.service.setRootViewContainerRef(this.viewContainerRef);
this.service.addDynamicContactComponent();
}
```

The Typescript code calls the address, Personal Details, and other components.
Now if I click on add form button for address and then switch to contact stepper I want to hide the address form and display the contact form.
Currently, the address from stays there and the contact form is displayed below it.

Currently this is how the page  looks in my app
[image]

[image]

If I change tabs I should be able to hide and show forms seperately for each stepper option.

Comment: why do you need dynamic component?? In the end you need to post the form, isn't it??

Comment: Because the form is too big and has lot of details.However each customer may not have all the information so I broke it into components and I am calling them dynamically. btw yes in the end I just need to submit a form that's all

Comment: actually, when you open the Address form and then switch to contact, Address form will be hidden. I am confused about why you need to remove this? because you need to create it again when user click on address again.

Comment: @SadidKhan I have updated my question please look at the pics. I want to be able to show/hide forms depending on which stepper I am on.

Comment: yes, you don't need to create and remove dynamically. but you can create seperate form for each step. the reason it is not hiding is you place the dyamic content outside of mat-step. use simple form in each mat-step. follw this link https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#using-a-different-form-for-each-step